# Spectral decompostion of a linear operator in Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I am having trouble calculating the countinuous spectrum of the following operator, as defined by their action on an orthonormal base of the Hilbert space:
$$ A(\phi_k)=e^{-k^2}\phi_k $$ Being $\{\phi_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ the orthonormal base.
I have figured out that $\lambda_k=e^{-k^2}$ are all eigenvalues,and that the inverse is such that the resolvent $R_\lambda=(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is such that:
$R_\lambda (\phi_k)=(e^{-k^2}-\lambda)^{-1}\phi_k$$, and that it is not bounded in the eigenvalues, and only there. Can I say then that the countinuous spectrum is empty?

Comment: How can the spectrum be empty when clearly each $e^{-k^2}$ is an eigenvalue?

Comment: Because the continuous spectrum is disjoin with the punctual spectrum (that is, the set of eigenvalues)

Comment: I've never heard these terms. You aren't talking about the resolvent set, are you?

Comment: Actually it is  a part of the complement of the resolvent set. I've also heard the continuous spectrum being called "approximate point spectrum", whereas the set of eigenvalues would be "point/punctual spectrum".

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\phi_k = e^{-k^2}\phi_k$ for every basis vector $\phi_k$ you can construct matrix representations of $A$ on the ascending chain of subspaces $span\{\phi_1\} \subset span\{\phi_1,\phi_2\} \subset \cdots$. Yyou can argue by induction that this process will form a complete representation of $A$ in the limit as the number of basis vectors becomes infinite. In particular, since $A$ consists only of its eigenvalues (plus zeros) in any finite projection, induction on $n$ shows the spectrum of this representation will be exactly the set $\{e^{-k^2}\}_k.$